# Stream 3gp media content through ffserver to mobile devices

Tags: streaming, 3gp, ffserver

I want to use FFserver to stream my 3gp content to mobile devices. I understand that ffserver needs an input feed in `.ffm` format. I am not sure what this format is. Does ffserver support streaming of 3gp contents?

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://ffmpeg.org/sample.html

ffmpeg and ffserver documentation can be found at: http://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html